# The input text value is not Passed to another page

Tags: jsp

I am trying to pass the text value to another jsp page and all the elements are created dynamically. I am not able to receive those values in another page even though the names are correctly assigned. Please Help me out to find the error. Thanks in advance!!!
This is the first page.

### firstpage.jsp

```
            <%!
                int wellname_counter = 0 ;
            %>

            <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
                SELECT * FROM work_history WHERE from_date >= ? ;
                <sql:param value="${from_date}"/>
            </sql:query>

                <center>
                <table class="table-fill">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Select The Well</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Well No</th>
                        <th class="text-center">From Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center">To Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Job Done</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Rig</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <form action="Generate-Excel/work_history.jsp" method="POST">
                    <tbody class="table-hover">

                        <% wellname_counter = 0 ;%>

                        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="name<%= wellname_counter %>" id="select_element" value="<%= wellname_counter %>">
                            </td>

                            <!-- For getting the name from well_sno attribute --> 

                            <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="wellname">
                                SELECT name FROM well_name WHERE sno = ? ;
                            <sql:param value="${row.well_sno}"/>
                            </sql:query>

                            <td class="text-center">

                            <c:forEach var="only_wellname" items="${wellname.rows}">
                                <input type="text" value="<c:out value="${only_wellname.name}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="well_name<%= wellname_counter%>">
                            </c:forEach>
                            </td>

                            <td class="text-center"><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.from_date}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="fromdate<%=wellname_counter%>"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.to_date}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="todate<%=wellname_counter%>"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.jobdone}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="jobdone<%=wellname_counter%>"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.rig}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="rig<%=wellname_counter%>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <%wellname_counter++ ; %>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>


                </table>

                     <input type="hidden" value="<%= wellname_counter %>" name="work_instance">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" class="styling"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="GENERATE EXCEL SHEET" class="green"/>
                       </div>
                      </form>
                  </center>
```

### Secondpage.jsp

```
        out.print( request.getParameter("name0") ) ;
        out.print( request.getParameter("fromdate0") ) ;
        out.print( request.getParameter("todate0") ) ;
        out.print( request.getParameter("jobdone0") ) ;
        out.print( request.getParameter("rig0") ) ;
```

Comment: Change `value="<c:out value="${row.from_date}"/>"` to `value='<c:out value="${row.from_date}"/>'` i.e. nesting of quotes

Comment: I tried it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fond the solution I should not have "disabled='true'" instead "readonly"

```
<input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.from_date}"/>" disabled="true" class="remove_border" name="fromdate<%=wellname_counter%>">
```

This the correct way to put the soultion

```
<input type="text" value='<c:out value="${row.from_date}"/>' class="remove_border" name="fromdate<%=wellname_counter%>" readonly>
```